# PowerQuery problem with refreshing dataflow - dynamic parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm struggling with a PowerBI service problem about refreshing dynamic parameters in PowerBI.

I import data from: https://www.margonem.pl/ladder/players,Aether?page=2 . Aether means a server, and 2 means the number of pages. So my dataset looks like the below:

| server | page |
| --- | --- |
| Aether | 1 |
| Aether | 2 |
| Aether | 3 |

So, my code is here:

```
=Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.margonem.pl", [RelativePath="/ladder/players,"&[Server]&"?page="&[Page]&""])))
```

I used RelativePath to handle dynamic parameters and It works only for Web.Contents

I have to get HTML code from the website by using Web.BrowserContents, but I cannot use ReleativePath workaround to set automatically refreshing my data. Could you help me?

---

Update:
I have to extract HTML code from this page, but I have to do it for about 7,000 pages, so I created a function to get it:

```
(Server as text, Page as text) =>
let
    #"HTML Code" = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.margonem.pl/ladder/players,"&Server&"?page="&Page&""),
    #"Split Text" = Text.Split(#"HTML Code", "profile"),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Split Text", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Text.StartsWith([Column1.1], "/view")),
    #"Inserted Text Between Delimiters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Char", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1.2], " ", "                                ", 35, 0), type text),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Inserted Text Between Delimiters",{"Column1.1", "Char"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns1"
```

So, if I want to set it automatically refreshing, then I receive a message:

> Can't save dataflow
>
> One or more tables references a dynamic data source.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine. What exactly is the problem?

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WckwtyUgtUtJRMlSK1UHiGqFyjZViYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Server = _t, Page = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.margonem.pl", [RelativePath="/ladder/players,"&[Server]&"?page="&[Page]&""]))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [Custom]{0}[Data]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom.1", {"#", "Gracz", "Poziom", "Profesja", "PH", "Ostatnio online"}, {"Custom.1.#", "Custom.1.Gracz", "Custom.1.Poziom", "Custom.1.Profesja", "Custom.1.PH", "Custom.1.Ostatnio online"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom.1"
```

Second try to get HTML.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WckwtyUgtUtJRMlSK1UHiGqFyjZViYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Server = _t, Page = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Web.BrowserContents("https://www.margonem.pl/ladder/players,"&[Server]&"?page="&[Page]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is wrong, because I have to get HTML code, not a table. HTML code is needed to extract some <body> information.

Comment: I'll update the answer

Comment: And it's still not working. Dynamic parameters are not allowed to set automatical refreshing in PowerBI service, but using [RelativePath] I can make the workaround, but it doesn't work with Web.BrowserContents :(